# struct* Assignment statements shows warning

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

It is a code for Linkedlist implementation in C with only one function i.e Insert an element at the beginning of the list

```
#include<stdio.h>
    struct node{
    char data;
    struct node* next;
};
int main()
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    head = InsertAtbeginning(head,'g'); //C4047
    head = InsertAtbeginning(head,'f'); //C4047
}

struct node* InsertAtBeginning(struct node* head, char key)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    temp->data = key;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    return head; 
}
```

While compiling in vscode I get the warning on the lines commented

> Warning C4047: '=': 'node *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

How!!? I'm not returning any int value. And both the left and right operands are of the same type i.e. struct node* then how..? Any idea why it happened?

Comment: Please do not break question by editing. New question should be posted as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

No declaration nor definition of `InsertAtbeginning` is given at the point the function is used, so the compiler is assuming that it returns `int`.

Add declaration or move the definition before where you use that to fix.

Also note that the line

```
    struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
```

is wrong because

- It is allocating only room for one pointer while you have to allocate for the structure.
- Casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

It should be:

```
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
```

or (if you want to stick to write type name for `sizeof`:

```
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Fixed code (add declaration):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    char data;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node* InsertAtBeginning(struct node* head, char key); // declaration
int main()
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    head = InsertAtbeginning(head,'g'); //C4047
    head = InsertAtbeginning(head,'f'); //C4047
}

struct node* InsertAtBeginning(struct node* head, char key)
{
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    temp->data = key;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    return head; 
}
```

Fixed code (move definition):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    char data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* InsertAtBeginning(struct node* head, char key)
{
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    temp->data = key;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    return head; 
}

int main()
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    head = InsertAtbeginning(head,'g'); //C4047
    head = InsertAtbeginning(head,'f'); //C4047
}
```

Comment: Warning Cxxxxx is MS compiler one so he is compiling it as C++ which is the default for this compiler. Without cast it will not compile in this case

Comment: @0___________ The code compiles as C with MSVC without the cast. [https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rY4z13qca](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rY4z13qca)

Comment: @0___________ I found that `#include <stdlib.h>` is missing. Added that and it still compiles. [https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5har3Krqa](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5har3Krqa)

Comment: Because in godbolt you **set** the language (in a top right corner of the edit panel) and system add the correct command line switch, without you even knowing about it. Try to compile on Windows

Comment: @0___________ Compiling as C++ gave me another error (identifier not found, C3861) instead of C4047, so the code must be compiled as C. [https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dq7KK5n84](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dq7KK5n84)

Answer (score 0):

You have many issues in this code.

1. `struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node*));` you do not allocate enough space as you allocate only size of the pointer not size of the struct. It has to be struct `node* temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));`
2. Your linked list is not terminated by NULL only pointed to the previous head.
3. You call the function without the prototype. The parameter is set as default to `int` -  thus warning.
4. You use MS compiler which by default compiles as C++. You need to change it to C. See the compiler documentation to find the command line switch.
5. Your `main` definition is wrong. It should be `int main(void)`

Comment: 1. Oh yes thanks for pointing it out. I was my mis.

2. It is terminated by NULL, because head was initialized by NULL so no issues here

3. Actually it was a little more stupid mistake that this. I typed InsertAtbeginning() instead of InsertAtBeginning(). So parameter is set by default to int everytime an undefined function is used?


4. How do I know the current language? I saved the file as .c instead of .cpp so I was positive it would be compiled as C.